# Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. u'INSERT INTO "Contacts"

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

> I have a wtform in contact.html and wanna display the data that user enter in info.html 
>   when I press submit to redirect to info.html
>   got error InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. u'INSERT INTO "Contacts" (name, email, subject, message) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'

```
  @app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
  def contact():
  form = LoginForm()
     if request.method == 'POST':
      if form.validate()== True:
      newcontact = Contacts(name=form.name,
                                 email=form.email,
                                subject=form.subject,
                                message=form.message)

        db.session.add(newcontact)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(flask.url_for('info')) 

    else: 
     #If the form does not have all fields that are required 
        flash('All fields are required.') 
 return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

@app.route('/info', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def info():
  form = LoginForm()
  #fetch the first 
  contactinfo = Contacts.query.first()
  #Populate the form Not sure about this part?? 

  form.name = contactinfo.name 
  form.email = contactinfo.email
  form.subject = contactinfo.subject
  form.message = contactinfo.message
  #returns the html page, along with the form        
  return render_template('info.html', form=form)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

> form.py

```
 class LoginForm(Form):
     name = StringField("Name", [validators.Required("Please enter your name.")])
     email = StringField("Email", 
     [validators.Required("Please enter your email  address."),
     validators.Email("Please enter valid email address.")])
     subject = StringField("Subject", 
     [validators.Required("Please enter your subject.")])
     message = StringField("Message", 
     [validators.Required("Please enter your  message.")])
     submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

> model.py

```
     class Contacts(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = "Contacts"
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
     name = db.Column(db.String(50))
     email = db.Column(db.String(50))
     subject = db.Column(db.String(50))
     message = db.Column(db.String(50))
```

> info.html

```
     {% extends "layout.html" %}
     {% block content %}
       <h2>show the info</h2>
      {% for entry in form %}
         name: {{ entry.name}} <br>
         email: {{ entry.email }} <br>
         subject{{ entry.subject }} <br>
         messaget {{ entry.message }} <br>
        <br>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the form fields, not their values, to your model fields. The value is stored in each field's `data` attribute.

```
newcontact = Contacts(
    name=form.name.data,
    email=form.email.data,
    subject=form.subject.data,
    message=form.message.data)
```

Comment: Thanx that fix the problem But would you please tell me in info.html {% for contactinfo  in contacts %} {{ contactinfo .name}} is true coz It show empty? @dirn

Comment: Because the field itself evaluates to true. If you want to check the value, you need to use `.data`.

Comment: No i don't want to check it just want to show the stored field in database in info.html and the question is what should be instead of ? {% for? in ? %} Thanx @dirn

Comment: Well since now of your endpoints pass `contacts` to a template I have no idea what it is.